# How to find the set for which a function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

LEt $f(z) = Im( z + \frac{1}{z} ) $. I need to find the set where $f$ is harmonic. IS there a way to find this without too much computations?

Comment: What do you know about harmonic functions?

Comment: $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Almentoe has shown that $f$ is harmonic is the punctured plane that deleted the origin, here we analyze the problem directly - "brute force."

First, note that we can write for $z\ne 0$

$$f(z)=\text{Im}\left(z+\frac1z\right)=y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$

Then, for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$, we have

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{2y(y^2-3x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3} \tag 1$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{2y(y^2-3x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3} \tag 2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals that for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$,

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0$$

We conclude that $f$ is harmonic for $z\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic everywhere but at $0$, this means that the real and imaginary parts satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations if $z \neq 0$, this imples that $g$ is harmonic for $z \neq 0$. Hence the real and imaginary parts are harmonic for $z \neq 0.$ So all you need to show is that $f$ is not defined at $z \neq 0$, and you're done!

Comment: This is the best way forward.

Comment: @ Dr. MV, he might not know the required theorems, I would say your approach might be better for him.

Comment: Well, I just gave you a +1!