# Showing a region where a functions is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{ y}{(x-1)^2+y^2} $. I want to find the region where $f$ is harmonic.

#### Try:

We know $f$ is analytic everywhere except at $(1,0)$. Hence, $f$ is harmonic everywhere except on $(1,0)$. Is this correct? or do I have to carry out the derivations?

Comment: because $(1,0)$ makes the denominator $0$

Comment: Yes, but suppose $f=x-iy$.  That function is not analytic anywhere.  So, existence does not imply analyticity.

Comment: I suppose he could use the fact that a rational function (poly / poly) is analytic where it is continuous?

Comment: As a rational function, it is indeed analytic except where the denominator is $0$, but analytic does not imply harmonic. Maybe you are thinking of complex variables where if the function is analytic, its real and imaginary parts are harmonic. But this is not a complex function of a single complex variable.

Comment: I was commenting on the bit about analyticity @ Dr. MV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not need to establish that $f=\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ is harmonic by taking partial derivatives directly.  If we observe that the function $f$ given by

$$\text{Im}\left(\frac1{1-z}\right)=\frac{y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

and if we know that $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere in the punctured plane (i.e., the plane less the point $(1,0)$), then both its real and imaginary parts are harmonic functions.  So, we are done.

We can prove the general result that the real and imaginary parts of an analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ are harmonic by first developing the [Cauchy-Riemann equations (CRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Complex_differentiability); $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Then, it is straightforward to show from the CRE that the real and imaginary parts are harmonic.

So, one can circumvent taking partial derivatives of $f$ by using the aforementioned theorems.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{h(z)} = \frac{1}{z-1}$, then $h$ is anti-holomorphic for $z \neq 1$, so $h$ is harmonic if $z \neq 1$.

Also $\Im(h)(x+iy) = \frac{y}{(x-1)^2 +y^2} $...

Or you could brute-force it in a similar manner to [How to find the set for which a function is harmonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455917/how-to-find-the-set-for-which-a-function-is-harmonic/1455945#1455945)

Comment: Well done again.  +1

Comment: Oh no, your answer made mine look complicated and show-offy!

Comment: Not at all.  Yours is mature and succinct.